# Nodejs output mongodb to html page

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I try to combine two sample code, one is showing html file using node js, the other is accessing database using node js. When I try to combine these code, I cannot achieve my target to show the database query to HTML page.

Here's my code:

```
var http = require('http');

var fs = require('fs');

// Database
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});

res.write('<br><h1>Hello World!</h1>');
res.write('<br><h2>Access Database</h2>');

var dbresult='1. test \n';

MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, db) {
    //if (err) throw err;
    if (err) {
        console.error('There was an error connecting to mongodb', err);
    }

    var dbo = db.db("testdb");

    // findone()

    dbo.collection("products").findOne({}, function(err, result) {
        //if (err) throw err;
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error calling findOne()', err);
        }
        //res.write("\n1. ");
        //res.write(result.name);
        console.log("\n1. ");
        console.log(result.name);
        dbresult += result.name;
        res.write(dbresult);
        db.close();
    });   
});

//res.write(dbresult);

res.end();
/*fs.readFile('demofile1.html', function(err, data) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(data);
    res.end();
  });*/
}).listen(8080);
```

If I put res.write() inside Mongoclient.connect() console will show "Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end".

If I put res.write() after Mongoclient.connect(), no data is shown. I've tried using console.log, no problem.

What's wrong in my code? Thank you...

Comment: You nedd to put `res.end()` inside callback function of `dbo.collection` i.e. just after `res.write(dbresult)`

Comment: Well, yes it worked if I put res.end() just below res.write(dbresult). I think this is because async function call.

Comment: Yes indeed it is due async function.